# Declination of adjective

Tags: grammar, adjective

In the following sentence:

> Ihr habt lange darauf gewartet.

For the adjective "lange", what is the declination in this case? Here we don't have defined or undefined articles so by the position I would say it should be accusative but then we have two possibilities: feminine and plural (declination with no article). Why should "darauf" be feminine or why should it be plural? Do I need the whole context to be able to point out the gender of what it is meant by "darauf"?

Answer (score 6):

In fact, [*lange*](http://dictionary.reverso.net/german-english/lange) is an adverb here, and therefore requires no declension. *Darauf* is not a noun, but rather a prepositional phrase. The sentence means, roughly,

> You have been waiting for that for a long time.

Answer (score 2):

In this sentence, *lange* is an adverb describing the verb *warten* and as such is not declined at all.

*darauf* is a preposition. Prepositions have no gender and are neither singular nor plural.

Comment: Not really a preposition; _auf_ is a preposition, but _darauf_ is a [pronominal adverb](http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Pronomen/PronAdv/Funktion.html?lang=en).

Comment: @chirlu Ok, feel free to edit